# Reading a boost::variant type from istream

Tags: c++, boost, boost-variant

I was going through `boost::variant` and wondering how can I make following to work ?

```
typedef boost::variant<int,std::string> myval;
int main()
{

std::vector<myval> vec;

std::ifstream fin("temp.txt");

//How following can be achieved ?
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<myval>(fin), //Can this be from std::cin too ?
          std::istream_iterator<myval>(),
          std::back_inserter(vec));   
}
```

For classes data members we have option to overload `>>` operator, but how to do this with `myval` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can overload `operator>>` for `variant` just like for any other type. But it is up to you to implement the logic to decide what type is read from the stream and stored in `variant`. Here's a complete example of how you might go about it:

```
#include "boost/variant.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

typedef boost::variant<int, std::string> myval;

namespace boost { // must be in boost namespace to be found by ADL
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, myval& v)
{
    in >> std::ws;      // throw away leading whitespace
    int c = in.peek();
    if (c == EOF) return in;  // nothing to read, done

    // read int if there's a minus or a digit
    // TODO: handle the case where minus is not followed by a digit
    // because that's supposed to be an error or read as a string
    if (std::isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(c)) || c == '-') {
        int i;
        in >> i;
        v = i;
    } else {
        std::string s;
        in >> s;
        v = s;
    }
    return in;
}
} // namespace boost

// visitor to query the type of value
struct visitor : boost::static_visitor<std::string> {
    std::string operator()(const std::string&) const
    {
        return "string";
    }
    std::string operator()(int) const
    {
        return "int";
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<myval> vec;
    std::copy(
        std::istream_iterator<myval>(std::cin),
        std::istream_iterator<myval>(),
        std::back_inserter(vec));

    std::cout << "Types read:\n";
    for (const auto& v : vec) {
        std::string s = boost::apply_visitor(visitor(), v);
        std::cout << s << '\n';
    }
}
```

Example input: `1 2 3 hello 4 world`

Output:

```
Types read:
int
int
int
string
int
string
```

Comment: that's really nice way. But for some reason I get all as `string` . I'm using MingW 4.7.2

Comment: @P0W You mean all strings in output? Even if you input integers and with the exact code I posted?

Comment: @P0W Nevermind, there was a silly mistake in `if` statement, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

`myval` is just a type. You overload operators based on types.

```
std::istream &operator >>(std::istream &stream, myval &val)
{
    //Put stuff here.
}
```

As for what to put there, that's *entirely* up to you and what you expect or require there to be in the stream.

Comment: Will this operator participate in the name look-up? I'm afraid you have to put it in either `boost` or `std` namespace.

Comment: @NicolBolas `std::istream &operator >>(std::istream &stream, myval &val) { return stream>>val; }` doesn't compile.
However `myval x; std::cin>>x;` compiles (after overloading) but the executable crashes

Comment: @NicolBolas, thanks, now I get what you were trying to say by correlating with jrok's example