# Can I get input without declaring a variable type or declare multiple type for same variable in c++?

Tags: c++

I want to get a input that can be integer or string and want to pass it to overloaded function, so that candidate function can be automatically detected and output generated. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You can use templates.

Comment: @gartenriese templates won't help here. He wants to follow a different code path depending on whether the user enters a number or not.

Comment: An example of the code you've tried and failed with, with annotations regarding what you're hoping would happen, would be considerably helpful. As-written you're asking for compile-time candidate selection by-value rather than by type-deduction (or so it appears). And to that i would answer no. If that isn't an accurate description of what you're trying to do, you need to post more info.

Comment: Input is *always* a string. Think about that.

Comment: @dvnrrs: Wouldn't something like this work: T getInput(); auto x = getInput();

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to do it *automatically*, but you can certainly do it programmatically.

- Read in a string.
- Check if the string is a valid number.
- If it is a number, get its value (via [atoi()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) or similar) and pass it to the integer version of your function.
- Otherwise, pass the string to the string version of your function.

There is no way to get this "for free" since the compiler can't know at compile time whether the input is going to be a number or not.

Comment: Can you please suggest me a good way to check the string if it is a valid number. I am quite new to c++ (also programming as a whole)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use [boost](http://www.boost.org/), the nearest thing I can imagine that does what you want is to use a [`boost::variant<int,std::string>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/variant.html) and overload the `>>` stream operator, like in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18012053/1431286).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Boost's lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html), or less complicated (depending on what you need), std::strtol() or string streams:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

void Process( const long         num ) { std::cout << "int: " << num << "\n"; }
void Process( const std::string& str ) { std::cout << "str: " << str << "\n"; }

int main()
{
    std::string s;
    while( std::cin >> s )
    {
        char* end;
        const auto i = std::strtol( s.c_str(), &end, 10 );
        if( end == s.c_str() + s.length() )
            Process( i );
        else
            Process( s );

        std::istringstream iss( s );
        int j;
        if( iss >> j )
            Process( j );
        else
            Process( s );
    }
}
```

With the input "abc 123", I get the output:

```
str: abc
str: abc
int: 123
int: 123
```